# In Prison Architect, can external staff members (e.g. teachers) access Staff Only areas?

Tags: prison-architect

In Prison Architect, can external staff members (e.g. teachers) access Staff Only areas?

2nd similar question.
Can visitors go through Staff Only or MinSec(Med/High) Only areas?

Comment: If they are carrying a Staff Key then they can go through Staff Doors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Staff Only setting restricts access to prisoners. Anyone who is not a prisoner is fine to go there.

Visitors will go as they please to get to visitation rooms assigned to areas available to prisoners they visit (e.g. visitation room for MedSec - visitors should and will go there if they are visiting a MedSec prisoner).